# how to use wget to list all links?

Tags: linux, wget

using `wget` i want to use to list even unmentioned links of a site?
how does `wget` work in this situation?

can it download the entire site even unmentioned links which has no https and no encryption and no vpn?

I get `wget -r --no-clobber` but how do i just see all the links without downloading.

But it's important I download the entire site.
If i know the URL i can directly open the site.

and if they are hidden, i mean-not mentioned in the web pages. how do i see them. if i get the link i can just paste and open the site. but how do i get the links?

Comment: If "the link" is not in "the page" then there is not much you can do except brute force guessing.

Comment: Beside that `wget` cannot somehow "download the whole site", since "the whole site" is not some clearly defined term. `wget` can fetch a single object from an url, not more, not less.

Comment: wget can crawl and follow links. It will even convert relative links so they work on your local machine. I have used that in the past. I don't quite remember the syntax though. In the 3rd paragraph of the wget man pages it even mentions this. [edit]Just to clarify, wget only uses the files available, so if there are files that do not get linked to, wget doesn't know about them[/edit]

Answer (score 0):

Barring the requirement to get links not mentioned in the webpages, which you've been told is impossible, there's [an answer on Unix and Linux.SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/116990/85638):

```
lynx -dump -listonly https://www.example.com
```